# Substitution Caesar Cipher String Error

Tags: python, string, encryption

This program will encrypt a message. It will be a Caesar version of a Substitution encrypted message.
It will shift the letters by 5.

```
from string import *

original = raw_input("Enter your string: ") # prompts user for their desired string

def sub(input, x):
    alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
    newAlpha = alpha[x:] + alpha[:x]
    i = string.maketrans(alpha, newAlpha)
    return input.translate(i)

print sub(original, 5)
```

I'm not sure why there is

```
NameError: global name 'string' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing everything from string module using `from string import *` and then again calling `string`  top level module at `string.maketrans` and `string.ascii_lowercase`

Just use `maketrans(alpha, newAlpha)` and `ascii_lowercase`

Ideally importing everything from a module is not a good idea and best practice. You are cluttering namespace. Just import what you need or import high-level module.
for e.g.
`from string import maketrans,ascii_lowercase`
and then use
`i = maketrans(alpha, newAlpha)`
`alpha = ascii_lowercase`

or

`import string`
and then use
 `i = string.maketrans(alpha, newAlpha)`
`alpha = string.ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 2):

Use `import string` instead of `from string import *` for compatibility of the 
`sub` function with your importing method.